# python: sending a post request with onclick triggering a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, request, http-post

I'm trying to write a script to search all the published papers of a given scholar. Basically, I'm using python's Requests to send a POST request with some parameters(like searching options and the scholar's name). And I found I'm mainly dealing with a form like this(truncated and edited for simplicity):

```
<form name="searchForm" 
  method="post" 
  action="http://epub.cnki.net/kns/brief/default_result.aspx" 
  id="searchForm" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="collectSelectDB();">
    ...
    <div class="research">
        <span class="reopt" id="typeSelect">
            <select id="txt_1_sel" name="txt_1_sel" class="searchw8">
            <option value="AU$=|" selected="true">Author</option>
            ...              
        </span>          
        <input class="rekeyword" value="" id="txt_1_value1" name="txt_1_value1" ...>
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="researchbtn" 
               onclick="javascript: cnkiIndexSearchOnclick('&amp;ua=1.11');">
    </div>
...
```

One thing I'm not sure is the "button", which seems to trigger a javascript by a click(and later it produces a result page).

When I pass the parameters like this,

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

url = 'http://epub.cnki.net/kns/brief/default_restult.aspx'
name = u'李强'
payload = {'txt_1_value1' : name.encode('utf-8')}
r = requests.post(url, params = payload)
with open("results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

it just gives me an empty search result, and a search box filled with the author's name. I guess I'm not sending the POST request properly because of the "button" stuff. Is this also a kind of parameter? How can we deal with it?

Comment: find the `cnkiIndexSearchOnclick` function in the javascript and see if it's modifying the data in any way before posting or if it's just a validator.

Comment: @CasualDemon yes, I traced back the `cnkiIndexSearchOnclick`, and found it calls a function named `submitForm`, and it seems doing a lot of work... But does it actually mean to "modify the data"? (I'm not familiar to javascript...)